# Use exception variable in finally block

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, scope, try-catch

When running this example func:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Any, Optional

def func() -> Tuple[Any, Optional[Exception]]:
    exc = None
    ret = None
    try:
        # code here, if successful assign result to `ret`
        ret = "Result"
        # comment this line out and the code works
        raise Exception
    except Exception as exc:
        exc.__traceback__ = None
        # Error logging here
        pass
    finally:
        return ret, exc

print(func())  # expected: ("Result", <Exception instance>)
```

the last line (`return ret, exc`) raises `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'exc' referenced before assignment` even tho `exc` is definitively bound in the first line of the function (`exc = None`). This can be fixed by changing the `except`-clause like so:

```py
except Exception as exc1:
    exc = exc1
    exc.__traceback__ = None
    # Error logging here
    pass
```

**Questions**:

1. Is it possible to avoid using another variable (in my example `exc1`) while still avoiding the `UnboundLocalError`?
2. Why does the `except <Exception> as <var>` statement "swallow" already defined local variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is described in [8.4. The try statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> When an exception has been assigned using as target, it is cleared at the end of the except clause. This is as if
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>    foo
> ```
>
> was translated to
>
> ```
>    try:
>        foo
>    finally:
>        del N
> ```
>
> This means **the exception must be assigned to a different name to be able to refer to it after the except clause**. Exceptions are cleared because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive until the next garbage collection occurs.